# How to share a link to a React app route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm using using react 17 and `react-router-dom` 6 within my client side app.
I want my users to have the ability to share links between each other like this one `https://example.com/id/8dcbe502-cc71-4199-8dfa-b84377d6b066`. But when I'm trying to open the link, I get an error from my server. I guess that's because the react app has not been loaded at this time and the path does not exists physically on the server. The app is hosted with AWS amplify hosting.

When clicking on a link pointing to localhost with the react app running locally, everything works fine and the desired component gets rendered.

How to properly handle such case and share links to a react app route?

Comment: you can conditionally, using useState and useEffect to try to request all the data and render loading component if its loading and return the app when its done from all requests

Comment: this would not work in my case. The data set is too large to load initially and also kind of secret. a user should only be able to load content of a uuid which he/she already has. hence the need to share the uuid link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the simplest solution for me was to switch to a react framework which supports sharing links. I decided for next.js. Now its working.

Comment: Hi @jan,  I'm have the same use case, and i'm interesting to know how do you handle it exactly. Do you have any documentation or useful links that explain that.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used a dynamic route with next.js (see https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes). With next.js in place and I guess the fact that my app wasn't a SPA anymore, the shared linked could be used without anymore problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is too late answer, but hope it will be useful for someone in future.

I experienced the same problem and solved it by adding `.htaccess` file with redirecting all routes to `index.html`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.html [L]
```

Sure, it will work only in case if only front-end app is located on your server.